# Align fo:float top-flush with wrapping text's ascender line

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

Is there a technique/method to align a side-float top flush with the ascender line of the text flowing around it?

Here's my example code:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pages">
      <fo:region-body margin-left="1in" margin-right="1in" margin-top="1in" margin-bottom="1in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:wrapper line-stacking-strategy="font-height" line-height.conditionality="discard" line-height="1.8" font-size="24pt">
    
      <fo:block space-after="2lh">
        <fo:float float="start">
          <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
            <fo:block>FLOAT-1</fo:block>
          </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    
        <fo:block space-after="2lh">
          <fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
              <fo:block>FLOAT-2</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    
      </fo:wrapper>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[image]

I think I understand why this is: For FLOAT-1, the `line-height.conditionality="discard"` of the wrapping `fo:block` kicks in at the top of the reference area and removes the upper half-leading portion. This is intended, so that any element in my document starts at the same perceived vertical position, be it a table, image or paragraph. However, when we're *not* at the top edge of a reference area, the upper portion of the half-leading is *not* discarded, and the `fo:float` aligns with the before edge of the line box (not the before edge of the nominal-requested-line-rectangle).

Is there a programmatic, universal technique to have floats anchored at the start of a paragraph align with the paragraph font's ascender line, not its first line box?

I'd like to have FLOAT-2 be aligned the same way visually as FLOAT-1, in any potential location throughout the document. Generally wrapping each and every paragraph also in an outer `fo:block-container` is likely not an option in my case, as that would have spacing/layout side-effects in many other places, I fear…

I am trying with Antennahouse FO Formatter 7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the floats are graphics, you can use the `axf:initial-letters` extension (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.initial-letters) to position and size the graphics.
- You can specify `space-before` on the `fo:block-container` in the float.
- I'm not sure why the `line-height.conditionality="discard"` isn't always applied, but you can get it back with an `fo:initial-property-set`.
- You can set `axf:baseline-grid="new"` on each `fo:block`.
- You can put an `fo:block-container` around each `fo:block` (although you've already discounted that option)

[image: Screenshot of five alternative solutions]

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
     xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions"
     line-height="1.8" font-size="24pt"
     line-stacking-strategy="font-height">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pages">
      <fo:region-body margin-left="1in" margin-right="1in" margin-top="1in" margin-bottom="1in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" axf:baseline-grid="new">
      <fo:block space-after="2lh" axf:initial-letters="2">
      <fo:external-graphic src="logo-antenna-200x200.png"/>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
      <fo:block space-after="2lh" axf:initial-letters="2">
      <fo:external-graphic src="logo-antenna-200x200.png"/>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" line-height.conditionality="discard">
    <fo:block space-after="2lh">
          <fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
              <fo:block>FLOAT-1</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
        <fo:block space-after="2lh">
          <fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black" space-before="(1lh - 1em) div 2" space-before.conditionality="retain">
              <fo:block>FLOAT-2</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" line-height.conditionality="discard">
      <fo:block space-after="2lh"><fo:initial-property-set line-height.conditionality="discard" />
      <fo:float float="start">
        <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
          <fo:block>FLOAT-1</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
      </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
      <fo:block space-after="2lh"><fo:initial-property-set line-height.conditionality="discard" />
      <fo:float float="start">
        <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
          <fo:block>FLOAT-2</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
      </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block space-after="2lh" axf:baseline-grid="new">
      <fo:float float="start">
        <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
          <fo:block>FLOAT-1</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
      </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
      <fo:block space-after="2lh" axf:baseline-grid="new">
      <fo:float float="start">
        <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
          <fo:block>FLOAT-2</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
      </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" line-height.conditionality="discard">
      <fo:block space-after="2lh">
        <fo:float float="start">
          <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
            <fo:block>FLOAT-1</fo:block>
          </fo:block-container>
      </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
      <fo:block-container space-after="2lh">
    <fo:block>
          <fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
              <fo:block>FLOAT-2</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
      </fo:block-container>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

---

Another alternative that uses `text-altitude`:

```
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block space-after="2lh" text-altitude="0">
          <fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
              <fo:block line-height.conditionality="discard">FLOAT-1</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
        <fo:block space-after="2lh" text-altitude="0">
          <fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
              <fo:block line-height.conditionality="discard">FLOAT-2</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
```

---

`<fo:inline line-height.conditionality="discard">` around the `fo:float`:

```
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block line-height.conditionality="discard" space-after="2lh">
          <fo:inline line-height.conditionality="discard"><fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
              <fo:block>FLOAT-1</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float></fo:inline>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
        <fo:block line-height.conditionality="discard" space-after="2lh">
          <fo:inline line-height.conditionality="discard"><fo:float float="start">
            <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
              <fo:block>FLOAT-2</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float></fo:inline>Torem dolor amet adipisicing sed eiusmod incididunt labore dolore aliqua enim minim quis exercitation laboris ut ex commodo Duis irure in in velit cillum eu nulla Excepteur occaecat non sunt.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
```

The `fo:inline` is aligned with the dominant alphabetic baseline, and the `fo:float` is aligned with the top of the `fo:inline`.  It's not clear to me why `line-height.conditionality="discard"` should work on the `fo:inline`, but it does.

Comment: Thanks Tony, these are really creative ideas! In my case: (1) won't work, as it's complex content; (2) won't work as I'd need to know at FO generation time if the float is first on a page or not, which I don't know (flowing content); (3) seems to be the easiest if I only understood why it does what it does: why does this move the float down by a half-leading?; (4) seems promising and the next-easiest, though I have to read up on it more, and (5) is actually now back in the game, as I'd at least understand how it works. So either (4) or (5) it will be then. Thanks so much, very helpful!

Comment: `fo:initial-property-set` is like an `fo:inline` around the content of the first line, without you have to work out exactly what fits on the first line. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_initial-property-set) The baseline of the `fo:inline`-alike aligns to the baseline of the line area.

Comment: `text-altitude="0"` makes the text overflow its parent block area towards the before-edge, making a background shading or applying a border impossible. And I'm reluctant to use a method I don't understand (<fo:inline line-height.conditionality="discard"> around the fo:float): if the behaviour turns out to be non-conforming ("bug") and is changed at some later time, my design will break. I tried (4), but stumbled upon a strange issue where _lexical_ attribute order variation would lead to an attribute value error message on the value expression (answer from AH support pending). Thank you!

Comment: The lexical order problem was already found and fixed. The fix will be in the next maintenance release. I don't see the before-edge overflow with `text-altitude="0"` with my sample, but, as expected, the background and border extend further than normal in the after direction because the `text-altitude` shifted things.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Tony! — (5) just dropped off the list as well, as wrapping each fo:block also into an fo:block-container prevents floats that are taller than one paragraph's (i.e., fo:block's) height to be flown around by the subsequent paragraph as well (as it is a reference area). So it's (4) from your original list of suggestions that looks like a viable solution for my requirements, so I'll have to wait for the next release in December. Thanks again!